# Experiencing strange behavior in react using Visual Studio

Tags: reactjs

I am playing around with a simple task manager project in react. When I add values to my task list array, the render as expected. However when I add values to my categories array the screen goes blank/white and no messages appear in the error log. Has anyone encountered this or is there an error in my code I am overlooking perhaps? below is the taskbar.js

I have looked through the different console views to try and find any related errors but to no avail. Everything compiles fine.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TaskList from './taskList.js';
import TaskCategories from './taskCats.js';

class TaskBar extends React.Component
{
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        tasks:[], 
        task: '',
        categories:["Home","Work","Play"],
        cat: ''
    };
    this.addTask = this.addTask.bind(this);
    this.addCat = this.addCat.bind(this); 
}

addTask(e){

    if(this.state.task !== "")
    {
        var newTask = {

            text: this.state.task,
            key: Date.now(),
            categories:[]             
        };
        this.setState(() => {
            this.state.tasks.push(newTask);
        });
       this.setState({task: ''});
    }
   }

   addCat(e){

     if(this.state.cat !== "")
     {
         var newCat = {

             text: this.state.cat,
             key: Date.now(),
             tasks:[]

         };

         this.setState(() => {
             this.state.categories.push(newCat);
         });

        this.setState({cat: ''});
     }
 }

componentDidUpdate(){
    console.log(this.state.tasks);
    console.log(this.state.categories);
}

render(){
    return (
        <div className="inputArea cols-md-6">
            <input 
             value = {this.state.task}
             placeholder = "Enter task" 
             onChange = {(event) => 
 this.setState({task:event.target.value})} />
            <input type="button" value="Add Task" onClick={this.addTask} 
/>

            <input 
         value = {this.state.cat}
         placeholder = "Enter category" 
         onChange = {(event) => this.setState({cat:event.target.value})} 
/> 
        <input type="button" value="Add Category" onClick={this.addCat} 
/>    
        <br /><br />    
            <div>
                <TaskList tasks={this.state.tasks} categories= 
   {this.state.categories}/>
            </div>
    </div>   
      )   
    }    
}

export default TaskBar;
```

I would expect a new category will be added to the category list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to pass new array and not mutate original and you aren't setting the state property

Try this approach for your arrays

```
this.setState({tasks: [...this.state.tasks, newTask]});
// and 
this.setState({categories: [...this.state.categories, newCat]})
```